# Find user that created object in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find the user that created an object, a package in this case, in an oracle database. I've been using this query:

```
SELECT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE ='PACKAGE';
```

However, this only shows me the owner. is there a way to find the user that created the package?

Comment: `Owner` is same as `USER`. What is the doubt all about.

Comment: @XING : It need not be right?. What if another user has create privileges for the owner's schema.?  `create package owner.package_name as ...`. The owner from all_objects would still appear as the actual owner and not the created user.

Comment: @KaushikNayak In that case i expect that information in the question. I dont believe in assumption my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three different things: schema which object belongs to, Oracle account used to execute CREATE statement and real person (OS user as so on) who made this command.

Owner indicates first of it.

Second of this things is ambiguous. Usually owner is also the account used to create object, but not always. Object may be also either created by SYS or any account with CREATE ANY system privilege. In some cases object may be created via SYS procedure granted to some user - so he have no CREATE ANY privilege directly.

There are no used-by-default inbuilt tool for it. You should use some sort of DDL audit, depends of RDBMS version, maybe based on DDL trigger, maybe AUDIT command of 12c, maybe something else.

Determining real person is a most complex task. Sometimes it can be picked up from V$SESSION view (osuser, terminal), but not always.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, i'll try with the DDL and see if i can get some info from the object's metadata.